# Javafx TabPane not able to scroll to last Tab

Tags: javafx, scroll, tabpanel

```
package com.ge.health.signaturegenerator;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane.TabClosingPolicy;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main2 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Signature Generator");
        VBox rootBox = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootBox, 1600, 950, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("NewFile.css");
        rootBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #A9A9A9;");

        MenuBar bar = new MenuBar();
        bar.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #A9A9A9; -fx-border-color: black;  -fx-border-width: 0.5;");

        Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");
        fileMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Load"));

        bar.getMenus().add(fileMenu);
        bar.getMenus().add(new Menu("Help"));

        rootBox.getChildren().add(bar);

        GridPane headerPane = new GridPane();
        headerPane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        headerPane.setHgap(5);
        headerPane.setVgap(5);
        ColumnConstraints column1 = new ColumnConstraints(200);
        ColumnConstraints column2 = new ColumnConstraints(200);
        ColumnConstraints column3 = new ColumnConstraints(200);
        ColumnConstraints column4 = new ColumnConstraints(200);
        headerPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(column1, column2, column3, column4);

        Label ageLabel = new Label("Age : 68");
        Label heightLabel = new Label("Height : 180 cm");
        Label widthLabel = new Label("width : 75 cm");
        Button button1 = new Button("Generate Atlas");
        headerPane.add(ageLabel, 0, 0);
        headerPane.add(heightLabel, 1, 0);
        headerPane.add(widthLabel, 2, 0);
        headerPane.add(button1, 3, 0);
        headerPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #A9A9A9;");
        rootBox.getChildren().add(headerPane);

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        tabPane.setSide(Side.LEFT);
        tabPane.setTabMinHeight(300);
        tabPane.setTabMaxWidth(15);
        tabPane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;  -fx-border-width: 1; -fx-open-tab-animation: grow;");
        tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabClosingPolicy.UNAVAILABLE);

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            Tab tab = new Tab();
            Label l = new Label("Tab " + i + "Tab " + i + "Tab " + i + "Tab " + i);
            l.setStyle("-fx-rotate: 90;");
            l.setMinSize(200, 40);
            tab.setGraphic(l);
            tab.getGraphic().autosize();
            tab.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #A9A9A9;");
            tab.setClosable(false);

            ImageView imView = null;
            int j = i % 2;
            if (j == 0) {
                imView = new ImageView(new Image(
                        new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/502655636/Pictures/2016-08-19_17h23_08.png"))));
            } else {
                imView = new ImageView(new Image(
                        new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/502655636/Pictures/2016-08-19_17h07_40.png"))));
            }

            GridPane grid = new GridPane();
            VBox vbox = new VBox(imView);
            grid.add(vbox, 0, 0, 1, 6);
            grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;");

            TitledPane[] titledPaneTab = new TitledPane[6];
            for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
                GridPane buttonsGrid = new GridPane();
                buttonsGrid.setPadding(new Insets(5));
                buttonsGrid.setHgap(5);
                buttonsGrid.setVgap(5);
                ColumnConstraints buttonColumn1 = new ColumnConstraints(100);
                buttonsGrid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(buttonColumn1);

                buttonsGrid.add(new HBox(), 0, 0);
                Label read = new Label("Read pos. : ");
                read.setMinWidth(100);
                Label selected = new Label("Selected pos. : ");
                selected.setMinWidth(100);
                HBox box1 = new HBox(100, read, selected);
                buttonsGrid.add(box1, 0, 1);

                Button mark = new Button("Mark");
                mark.setMinWidth(100);
                Button delete = new Button("Delete");
                delete.setMinWidth(100);
                Button reset = new Button("Reset");
                reset.setMinWidth(100);
                HBox box2 = new HBox(10, mark, delete, reset);
                buttonsGrid.add(box2, 0, 2);
                buttonsGrid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #A9A9A9;");

                TitledPane ggg = new TitledPane("Parts " + i, buttonsGrid);

                ggg.setCollapsible(false);

                ggg.setMinWidth(400);
                ggg.setStyle("-fx-content-display: top;  -fx-border-insets: 20 15 15 15;  -fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;  -fx-border-color: black;  -fx-border-width: 1;");             

                titledPaneTab[k] = ggg;
            }
            VBox box2 = new VBox(titledPaneTab);
            grid.addColumn(1, box2);
            tab.setContent(grid);
            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
        }

        // bind to take available space
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
        borderPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());

        borderPane.setCenter(tabPane);
        rootBox.getChildren().add(borderPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Hello.

I'm trying to dev a javafx little application.

I faced a problem with javafx TabPane. If there more tabs than the stage can display, i just can't scroll to the bottom of the page.

An idea anyone.

I use this css also

```
.tab-pane *.tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: #000000;
}

.tab-pane  *.tab:selected {
    -fx-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

The result is below

[Tab Pane with scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCbK3.png)

The arrow shows up.

The problem is that i have 30 tabs in the header and i just can't scroll to the last one. Even when i select it through the arrow, it does not show up

Thank you

Comment: Could you be more specific? If you add e.g. 50 `Tab`s, normally you can scroll and also an arrow appears (which is done also for this example).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes the arrow shows up. The problem is that when i choose, let's say, the last tab, the tab header doesn't auto scroll to the bottom to show the selected tab

Comment: Someone to help please ?

Comment: Anyone please ? I need the info pretty quickly :)

Comment: You can put tabpane into scrollpane

Comment: Thank you so much. That works. It does not render like i would but i can see all the tabs now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can put tabpane into scrollpane – GlacialMan Aug 31 at 23:03

Thank you GlacialMan

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. To provide additional clarification, please edit the original post.